# Keeping Track of Totals in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to code an application that will keep track of the total amount of cars sold through the person's ID number.  I have coded it so that the car totals show in their respective fields but how do I get it so that the totals are saved after I input more ID numbers.  The below is the ID requirements.

The first number can be either 1 or 2.  1 is new cars sold while 2 is used cars sold.
The last letter of the ID is P (Part time) or F (Full Time).

The setup is like this:

```
ID:                                    Number of cars sold:
(Textbox to input ID#)         (Textbox to input number of cars sold)

Calculate Button                  Exit Button


Total of cars sold by full-time employees: (label to display total)
Total of cars sold by part-time employees: (label to display total)
Total of new cars sold: (label to display total)
Total of used cars sold: (label to display total)
```

Here's my code.  I want to keep a running total for each depending on the input ID number.  So if I put it 1MBP sold 7 cars and 1DKP sold 7 cars, the totals for new cars and part-time employee should show 14

```
' Name:         Huntington Motors Sales Application
' Purpose:      The application will calculate the number and type of cars sold as per
'                   input from the manager.  The ID number specifies the type of sales person
'                   sold the car which is how the application will calculate the total.
' Programmer:   Marlinda Davis on October 15, 2015

Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        Dim strId As String
        Dim intNumSold As Integer
        Dim intNew As Integer
        Dim intUsed As Integer
        Dim intPartTime As Integer
        Dim intFullTime As Integer

        ' identify characters in ID '
        strId = txtIDNum.Text.Trim.ToUpper
        Integer.TryParse(txtNumSold.Text, intNumSold)

        ' verify that the ID contains a number followed by 3 numbers 
        ' The first number 1 = new car sales person or 2 = used car sales person
        ' The next two letters are the person's initials
        ' The last letter indicates if the person is full time(F) or part time(P)

        If strId Like "[12][A-Z][A-Z][FP]" Then
            If strId.Substring(0) = "1" Then
                intNew = intNew + intNumSold
                lblNewNum.Text = intNew.ToString
            Else
                intUsed = intUsed + intNumSold
                lblUsedNum.Text = intUsed.ToString
            End If

            If strId.Substring(3) = "F" Then
                intFullTime = intFullTime + intNumSold
                lblFTNum.Text = intFullTime.ToString
            Else
                intPartTime = intPartTime + intNumSold
                lblPTNum.Text = intPartTime.ToString
            End If
        End If

        ' refocus on ID input box after each entry '
        txtIDNum.Focus()
        txtIDNum.SelectAll()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMain_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Const strEXIT As String = "Are you sure you want to close this application?"
        Dim dlgExit As DialogResult

        ' verify the user wants to close the application '
        dlgExit = MessageBox.Show(strEXIT, "Huntington Motors", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                  MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

        ' if the user answers No then the application will not close '
        If dlgExit = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am trying to get it to keep track of the totals with each ID that is input into it.  I have tried Do Loops and For Loops  but the Do Loops freeze and the For Loop counts each one.  The code that I have there changes the totals every time I put in a new ID but I need it to keep adding on to the previous totals with each ID input.